# close() was never explicitly called on database after database is imported

Tags: android, database, runtime-error, assets

I am getting the following error in my application. But, this error doesn't make my app crash. Nevertheless, I known what is causing this error but not sure how to fix it. As I pay more attention to this error is because I am coping my database from the Asset folder to /data/ folder. I use the same code throughout the app to ensure that the database exist if not copy it again. if the user deletes the database by mistake. That's the reason I use that code (I will past it below the error). As I did a research, this could be one of the causes that my app crashes due to outof memory error. Not sure if this causes a memory leak as well. Please help me. Like I said before, the app works fine until there is a outofmemory error. I want to fix all the error that I find starting with this one.

Error:

```
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.drakeillusion.yao1/databases/YAOMasterDB.db' 
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at com.example.yao.YAOMySQLiteHelper.openDataBase(YAOMySQLiteHelper.java:328)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at com.example.yao.SplashActivity.copydbfromassest(SplashActivity.java:128)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at com.example.yao.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:68)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
           01-08 17:22:44.326: E/Database(414):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Activity:
This is the first activity I call where I import the database from the asset folder to /data/ folder

```
      public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

String value;
String update = "01";
Boolean mastupdate = false;

private static String DB_PATHNAME = "/data/data/com.example.yao/database/YAOMasterDB.db";

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       copydbfromassest();

       // Show the splash screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    // Find the progress bar
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_progress_bar);
    // Start your loading
    new LoadingTask(progressBar, this).execute("127.0.0.1"); 



      Thread thread = new Thread(){

        /////@Override
        public void run(){
            //TODO Auto-generated nethod stub
            //super.run();
            try{

                sleep(1000);
                /////startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

            } catch (InterruptedException e){
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            //}finally{
            //  Intent a = new Intent (SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();


}


    ///copy the database from assest folder
private void copydbfromassest() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
YAOMySQLiteHelper myhelper = new YAOMySQLiteHelper (this);

try{
    //create datbase
    myhelper.importIfNotExist();
}catch (IOException e){
    throw new Error("Unable to Create the Database ");

}

try{
    myhelper.openDataBase();
}catch (SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle;
}


}


//// delete the database
private void deletedb() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

try{
File f = new File(DB_PATHNAME);
if (f.exists()){
    f.delete();
}
}catch (Exception ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}

}



    private void openfilelevel() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileInputStream fis;
        try{
            fis = openFileInput("update.ss");
            byte [] input =  new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(input) != -1){
                value = new String (input);

            }
            fis.close();
            if(!value.contentEquals(update)){
                mastupdate = true;
                createupdatelevel();
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }


        private void createupdatelevel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String FILENAME = "update.ss";
        String JOUR = update;
        try{
            File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
            mastupdate = true;
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, getBaseContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(JOUR.getBytes());
                fos.close();


        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /// text make the file
    private void makethefile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String FILENAME = "Update.ss";
        String JOUR = update;

        try{
            File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
            if (file.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                mastupdate = true;
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, getBaseContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(JOUR.getBytes());

            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public void onTaskFinished() {
    completeSplash();
    }

 private void completeSplash(){
    startApp();
    finish(); // Don't forget to finish this Splash Activity so the user can't return to it!
 }

 private void startApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is My "DatabaseHelper" called YAOMySQLiteHelper.
YAOMySQLiteHelper contains a lot of code I will past the corresponding sections.

```
 public class YAOMySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String db_path;

private String dbName;
private String dbNameFK;

private String dbImages;
   //private Context context;
 private final Context context;

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private static final String DATABASE_NAMEFK = "YAOMasterDB.jet";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "YAOMasterDB.db";

 public YAOMySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        this.dbNameFK = DATABASE_NAMEFK;
        this.dbName = DATABASE_NAME;

       // this.dbImages=DATABASE_IMAGES;

        this.context = context;
        db_path = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
      }

 public void importIfNotExist() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkExist();

        if (dbExist) {
            Log.i("Tag : ImportIfNotExist", "DB Exist : " + dbExist);
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            Log.i("Tag : ImportIfNotExist", "DB Not Exist : " + dbExist);
            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDatabase();

                //Deleteing a file (Database)
               // DeleteDBjet();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

 /*
  * Create a copy of the database from Asset folder to the android emulator
  */
    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

         Log.i("Tag : copyDatabase - Ininitail database", "Getting ready to Coping Database    From the database stored in Asset folder" );

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(dbNameFK);

   String RenameDB2OriginalName = "YAOMasterDB.db";
        String outFileName = db_path + RenameDB2OriginalName;   

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
       byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];  


    Log.i("Tag : copyDatabase - buffer Database", "Coping Database From the database stored in Asset folder" );
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }



        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();



        this.close();

    }    



            public boolean checkExist() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
                try {
            String myPath = db_path + dbName;

                File dbFile = new File( db_path + dbName);
                return dbFile.exists();



        } 
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();



            if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();


        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }



    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
            //Open the database
        String myPath = db_path + dbName;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }



        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
        super.close();

        }

        public void DeleteDBjet(){
            String myPath = db_path + dbName;

            File file = new File(myPath);
            boolean deleted = file.delete();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the database if you open it or if you are handling it globally then you don't have to open it again and again. But closing database would be a better option when not used in the activity anymore.

Change the method

```
private void startApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

to this

```
private void startApp() {
    myhelper.close();
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went back and I did what you said and placed it in the corresponding myhelper.close() and that error stopped popping up.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SplashActivity` (where the warning is coming from) `myHelper.close()` is never called.